# What is the scope of require_once in PHP?

Tags: php, scope, server-side-includes, require-once

Simple question: Is the scope of `require_once` global?

For example:

```
<?PHP

require_once('baz.php');

// do some stuff
foo ($bar);

function foo($bar) {
    require_once('baz.php');
    // do different stuff
}

?>
```

When foo is called, **does it re-parse baz.php?** Or does it rely on the already required file from the main php file (analagous to calling require_once twice consecutively for the same include file)?

I saw this thread before, but it didn't quite answer the question:

[Should require_once "some file.php" ; appear anywhere but the top of the file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1669707/should-require-once-some-file-php-appear-anywhere-but-the-top-of-the-file)

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`require_once()` basically relies on the physical file to determine whether or not it's been included.  So it's not so much the context that you're calling `require_once()` in, it's whether or not that physical file has previously been required.

In your code above, your `foo()` function would not re-parse `baz.php`, since it is going to be the same file as was previously included at the top.

However, you will get different results based on whether you included it inside `foo()`, or included it at the top, as the scoping will apply when `require_once()` does succeed.

Answer (score 5):

It does not. `require_once`'s tracking applies to inside functions.
However, the following scripts produce an error:

a.php

```
<?php
require_once('b.php');
function f() { require_once('b.php'); echo "inside function f;"; }
?>
```

b.php

```
<?php
f();
?>
```

because function f() is not pre-defined to `b.php`.

Answer (score 3):

To more specifically answer your question, the second time you call `require_once` on that file, it won't do anything, because it's already be included.

If your include has functions etc. in it, then you would have issues including it inside a function anyway, so scope is irrelevant. If it's just variables being defined or processed, then you can just use `require` instead of `require_once` if you want it to be included again, thereby redefining the variables in your scope.

Answer (score 0):

At least in PHP 7.3, `require_once` has global scope.
If it would not, both `x.php` and `z.php` should throw errors as `y.php` does:

a.php

```
<?php function a() { require_once 'b.php'; b(); }
```

b.php

```
<?php function b() { debug_print_backtrace(); }
```

---

x.php

```
<?php
require_once 'a.php';
a();
b();
```

-->

```
#0 c() called at [/var/www/b.php:2]  
#1 b() called at [/var/www/a.php:3]  
#0 c() called at [/var/www/a.php:4]
```

y.php

```
<?php
require_once 'a.php';
b();
```

--> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function b() in /var/www/y.php on line 3

z.php

```
<?php
require_once 'a.php';
require_once 'b.php';
b();
```

-->

```
#0 b() called at [/var/www/z.php:4]
```