# PHP - defining classes inside a function

Tags: php, oop, class, function

Is this a bad practice?

like:

```
function boo(){
  require_once("class.moo.php");
}
...
```

?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [#2619573](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2619573/how-to-use-include-within-a-function)

Comment: I think it's a dup of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1669707/should-require-once-some-file-php-appear-anywhere-but-the-top-of-the-file) actually

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Yes** it is bad practice; **no** it's not.

You're likely going to get both answers, and here's why:

If you use `__autoload` (or equivalent), calling:

```
function someFunc()
{
  $n = new UndefinedClassName();
}
```

is equivalent to:

```
function someFunc()
{
  include('path/to/UndefinedClassName.php');
  //may be require_once, include_once, include, or require
  //depending on how autoload is written
  $n = new UndefinedClassName();
}
```

But you'll get better performance out of your code if you avoid using `__autoload`. And to maintain your code, it's better to put all your `includes` at the top of the script like you would for `import` statements in other languages.

```
include('path/to/UndefinedClassName.php');
...code...
function someFunc()
{
  $n = new UndefinedClassName();
}
```

I would suggest consistency. If you consistently call the `include` in the functions, you shouldn't have too many issues, but I would choose imports at the beginnings of files, or as `autoloads`.

Comment: What if there are other declarations inside `UndefinedClassName.php` that are syntactically illegal when used inside a function definition?

Answer (score 5):

I would avoid it.

It is not what another developer would expect, and, as such, would reduce the maintainability of your code.

Comment: "it's not what another developer would expect" unless of course the other developer is doing the same thing...

Comment: @zzzzBov: Well, I mean a "normal" developer, of course.  Non-standard practices are bad practices, IMO.

Comment: i agree with what you're saying on some levels, but it's important to distinguish *which* standard you're talking about. There isn't an *official* standard, there is only the way other programmers have written code in the past. The closest thing to an *official* standard is the coding specification and syntax, which is liberal for a reason.

Comment: True - I'm not talking about an "official standard", but more of a "most common practice".  That being said, I never mentioned a "standard" in my answer for a reason ;)

Comment: @zzzzBov: I'd see it as similar to why I would say it's bad practice to use any of these without very good reason: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1995113/strangest-language-feature

Answer (score 1):

This is how class loaders work. This is not necessarily bad practice.

Depends on what the function does and why you are doing this. Using [autoloading](http://php.net/spl_autoload_register) may be more appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

This is generally a bad practice and should be avoided.  You should probably consider using an [autoloader](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php) instead.

Comment: Yes, but autoloader doesn't have the same readability/maintainability issues.

Answer (score 0):

If you have reasons for this I don't see anything bad about it.